# Write multiple values under one key in JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to create custom prefixes for my discord bot but I encountered a problem, the bot would only write one of the prefixes the user set.

This is what I have inside my JSON file

```
{"prefixes":"$"}
```

And this is the code I wrote in order for the prefix to be saved

```
fs.writeFile("./prefixes.json", JSON.stringify(prefixes), (err) => {
      if(err)
      console.log(err)
   })
```

I want to do something like this, for example. Could anyone let me know if this is possible, and if yes, how. I searched google for the fs.writeFile function but it didn't answer my question.

`{"prefixes":"$","!","$"}`

Answer (score 1):

Use an array

```
{
  "prefixes": ["$","!","$"]
}
```